# Define users on git (on local server) and give them different privileges

Tags: git

I have defined git on a local server, and able to clone from it and push to it from client PCs. 
The changes pushed to server are successful but does not appear immediately on my server repository. Also I don't know how to know, which client made which change.

I want to:

1. Be able to track changes made by different users
2. To have the push appear immediately on my server repository

Comment: Without knowing which git server you have and how it's configured your second point is nearly impossible to give an accurate answer to. As for your first post, have you looked at `git log`?

Comment: If you want to give different permissions to users, you will have to use some form of (potentially self-hostet) platform like GitLab or GitHub.